# How can I select a number of records per a specific field using mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents in mongodb, each of which have a "group" field that refers to a group that owns the document.  The documents look like this:

```
{
  group: <objectID>
  name: <string>
  contents: <string>
  date: <Date>
}
```

I'd like to construct a query which returns the most recent N documents for each group.  For example, suppose there are 5 groups, each of which have 20 documents. I want to write a query which will return the top 3 for each group, which would return 15 documents, 3 from each group.  Each group gets 3, even if another group has a 4th that's more recent.

In the SQL world, I believe this type of query is done with "partition by" and a counter.  Is there such a thing in mongodb, short of doing N+1 separate queries for N groups?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do this using the aggregation framework yet - you can get the $max or top date value for each group but aggregation framework does not yet have a way to accumulate top N plus there is no way to push the entire document into the result set (only individual fields).

So you have to fall back on MapReduce.   Here is something that would work, but I'm sure there are many variants (all require somehow sorting an array of objects based on a specific attribute, I borrowed my solution from one of [the answers in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript).

Map function - outputs group name as a key and the entire rest of the document as the value - but it outputs it as a document containing an array because we will try to accumulate an array of results per group:

```
map = function () { 
    emit(this.name, {a:[this]}); 
}
```

The reduce function will accumulate all the documents belonging to the same group into one array (via concat).  Note that if you optimize reduce to keep only the top five array elements by checking date then you won't need the finalize function, and you will use less memory during running mapreduce (it will also be faster).

```
reduce = function (key, values) {
    result={a:[]};
    values.forEach( function(v) {
        result.a = v.a.concat(result.a);
    } );
    return result;
}
```

Since I'm keeping all values for each key, I need a finalize function to pull out only latest five elements per key.

```
final = function (key, value) {
      Array.prototype.sortByProp = function(p){
       return this.sort(function(a,b){
       return (a[p] < b[p]) ? 1 : (a[p] > b[p]) ? -1 : 0;
      });
    }

    value.a.sortByProp('date');
    return value.a.slice(0,5);
}
```

Using a template document similar to one you provided, you run this by calling mapReduce command:

```
> db.top5.mapReduce(map, reduce, {finalize:final, out:{inline:1}})
{
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : "group1",
            "value" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("516f011fbfd3e39f184cfe13"),
                    "name" : "group1",
                    "date" : ISODate("2013-04-17T20:07:59.498Z"),
                    "contents" : 0.23778377776034176
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("516f011fbfd3e39f184cfe0e"),
                    "name" : "group1",
                    "date" : ISODate("2013-04-17T20:07:59.467Z"),
                    "contents" : 0.4434165076818317
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("516f011fbfd3e39f184cfe09"),
                    "name" : "group1",
                    "date" : ISODate("2013-04-17T20:07:59.436Z"),
                    "contents" : 0.5935856597498059
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("516f011fbfd3e39f184cfe04"),
                    "name" : "group1",
                    "date" : ISODate("2013-04-17T20:07:59.405Z"),
                    "contents" : 0.3912118375301361
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("516f011fbfd3e39f184cfdff"),
                    "name" : "group1",
                    "date" : ISODate("2013-04-17T20:07:59.372Z"),
                    "contents" : 0.221651989268139
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : "group2",
            "value" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("516f011fbfd3e39f184cfe14"),
                    "name" : "group2",
                    "date" : ISODate("2013-04-17T20:07:59.504Z"),
                    "contents" : 0.019611883210018277
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("516f011fbfd3e39f184cfe0f"),
                    "name" : "group2",
                    "date" : ISODate("2013-04-17T20:07:59.473Z"),
                    "contents" : 0.5670706110540777
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("516f011fbfd3e39f184cfe0a"),
                    "name" : "group2",
                    "date" : ISODate("2013-04-17T20:07:59.442Z"),
                    "contents" : 0.893193120136857
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("516f011fbfd3e39f184cfe05"),
                    "name" : "group2",
                    "date" : ISODate("2013-04-17T20:07:59.411Z"),
                    "contents" : 0.9496864483226091
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("516f011fbfd3e39f184cfe00"),
                    "name" : "group2",
                    "date" : ISODate("2013-04-17T20:07:59.378Z"),
                    "contents" : 0.013748752186074853
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : "group3",
                        ...
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 15,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 80,
        "emit" : 80,
        "reduce" : 5,
        "output" : 5
    },
    "ok" : 1,
}
```

Each result has _id as group name and values as array of most recent five documents from the collection for that group name.

Comment: value.a.sort((a,b) => (a.date > b.date) ? 1 : ((b.date > a.date) ? -1 : 0));  may be better than value.a.sortByProp('date');

Answer (score -1):

you need aggregation framework $group stage piped in a $limit stage...
you want also to $sort the records in some ways or else the limit will have undefined behaviour, the returned documents will be pseudo-random (the order used internally by mongo)

something like that:
     db.collection.aggregate([{$group:...},{$sort:...},{$limit:...}])

here there is the documentation [if you want to know more](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)

Comment: you are incorrect about limit having undefined behavior, and you are incorrect that this can give separate sorts per group - it cannot.

Comment: the behaviour is indeed undefined this is a video form M101J course for java developer from 10gen (company building mongo) the speaker is the Vice President of the education section at 10gen

and of course it could give you different sorts per group since is the definition of undefined behavior basically

https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=AdxoEzVqdtc

Comment: try it out yourself (with *current* version) you will see that it makes no difference what order you put limit and sort (sort, limit or limit, sort) you will get the same result as the internal pipeline optimization will handle them together to save on processing.  Btw, in regular query (find) order of limit and sort doesn't matter in current or any recent version (agg framework fixed that behavior for 2.4).

Comment: anyway, these are all side-points unrelated to the fact that you cannot limit aggregation framework group to first N elements for each unique key.  Feature request to be able to do that here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9377