# Aggregate group by query in MongoDB, showing top 5 $count results by date

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDb on the application stack, switching over from LAMP (mysql backend) to MEAP (mongo backend), so please forgive my ignorance of non-relational queries.

I am trying to do some simple analytics on the data in our MongoDb to present trends over time to the users for particular keywords.

My (simplified) collection object structure is like the following: (in BSON)

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("55aae6b21e76a5d02945ccbc"),
  "article" : {
    "category" : [{
        "title" : "Foods"
      }
    ]},
  "published" : new Date("7/17/2015 19:00:00")
}
```

Imagine there are many articles published each day, each with many possible "categories", so the object above was truncated for brevity.

I want to present to users a daily "top 5" count of the categories being published so they can get a sense of what is trending, etc...

Here is my attempt at an aggregate query in mongo,  which currently just sums all the categories regardless of the published date:

```
{ "$unwind": "$article.category" },
{"$group":
    {
        "_id":  "$article.category.title" ,
        "count": { "$sum" : 1 }
    }
},
{ "$sort" : { "count" : -1, "_id": 1} },
{ $limit : 5 }
```

Which yields results like this:

```
{ 0: {"_id": "Foods", "count": 50},
  1: {"_id": "Recipes", "count": 45},
   ...
}
```

Question:  How do I get the result to be grouped by the "published" date I have available in my collection?  The pseudo object would be structured something like:

```
Date: 7/17/2015
    category: Foods, count: 25
    category: Recipes, count: 20
    ... continue top 5 results for that date
Date: 7/18/2015
    category: Foods, count: 25
    category: Recipes, count: 25
    ... continue top 5 results for that date
etc...
```

Any help for this mongo newb is greatly appreciated.  I've been looking into putting two group by statements together,  and trying to figure out $push or $addtoset could help me, but i can't wrap my head around the documentation to make it work for my example

Answer (score 0):

What you're likely looking for is Mongo [Date Aggregation Operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/). What you need to do is group documents by category title AND the date using the `$year` and `$dayOfYear` (or `$month` and `$dayOfMonth`) operators so each element in your array will be unique by date and title.

Along with the operators, you'll need to run `map` on the results to limit the categories to the top 5 as I'm not aware of a way to do it straight in the aggregate call.

My strategy is:

1. Unwind the categories.
2. Group together and count by category and date (day and year).
3. Group by date with categories (and their counts) push to an array.
4. Use `map` on the results to slice off categories beyond the top 5.

This may be the query you're looking for:

```
db.articles.aggregate([{
  "$unwind": "$article.category"
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id":  {
      title: "$article.category.title",
      year: { $year: "$published" },
      day: { $dayOfYear: "$published" }
    },
    "count": { "$sum" : 1 }
  }
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: {
      year: "$_id.year",
      day: "$_id.day"
    },
    categories: {
      $push: { title: "$_id.title", count: "$count" }
    }
  }
}]).map( function (data) {
  // Using map here is the best way I could think to limit
  // the array size. Perhaps someone can do it all together
  // But this should do the trick.
  data.categories.sort( function (a, b) {
    return b.count - a.count;
  });
  data.categories = data.categories.slice(0, 5);
  return data;
});
```

And I would expect the result to look like this:

```
[{
  _id: {
    year: 2015,
    day: 123
  },
  categories: [{
    title: "Food",
    count: 3
  }, {
    title: "Recipes",
    count: 2
  }]
}, ...]
```

Comment: [Duplicate question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067288/how-can-i-select-a-number-of-records-per-a-specific-field-using-mongodb) ihas already been marked and several minutes before your response.

Answer (score 0):

Although currently it is not possible currently to splice an array with aggregation framework (this feature will be soon available in [mongoDB version 3.1.4](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6074) ) 
Still you can come very close to what you want with the followng pipeline:

```
[
{
    "$project": {
        "article": "$article",
        "yymmdd": {
            "$dateToString": {
                "date": "$published",
                "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    "$unwind": "$article.category"
},
{
    "$group": {
        "count": {
            "$sum": 1
        },
        "_id": {
            "yymmdd": "$yymmdd",
            "title": "$article.category.title"
        }
    }
},
{
    "$sort": {
        "_id.yymmdd": 1,
        "count": -1
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "item": {
            "$push": {
                "count": "$count",
                "item": "$_id.title"
            }
        },
        "_id": "$_id.yymmdd"
    }
}
```

]

which with some data will give you a result set in the form of:

```js
{u'item': [{u'count': 100, u'item': u'food'}, {u'count': 99, u'item': u'cinema'}, {u'count': 96, u'item': u'tennis'}, {u'count': 92, u'item': u'news'}, {u'count': 91, u'item': u'gossip'}, {u'count': 90, u'item': u'football'}, {u'count': 88, u'item': u'recipes'}, {u'count': 84, u'item': u'tv'}], u'_id': u'2015-05-31'}
{u'item': [{u'count': 96, u'item': u'gossip'}, {u'count': 93, u'item': u'news'}, {u'count': 92, u'item': u'food'}, {u'count': 91, u'item': u'football'}, {u'count': 87, u'item': u'tennis'}, {u'count': 84, u'item': u'recipes'}, {u'count': 84, u'item': u'cinema'}, {u'count': 82, u'item': u'tv'}], u'_id': u'2015-05-29'}
{u'item': [{u'count': 106, u'item': u'cinema'}, {u'count': 104, u'item': u'gossip'}, {u'count': 99, u'item': u'tv'}, {u'count': 98, u'item': u'news'}, {u'count': 96, u'item': u'football'}, {u'count': 94, u'item': u'food'}, {u'count': 93, u'item': u'tennis'}, {u'count': 90, u'item': u'recipes'}], u'_id': u'2015-05-25'}
{u'item': [{u'count': 85, u'item': u'football'}, {u'count': 85, u'item': u'gossip'}, {u'count': 81, u'item': u'cinema'}, {u'count': 80, u'item': u'tennis'}, {u'count': 78, u'item': u'news'}, {u'count': 74, u'item': u'recipes'}, {u'count': 70, u'item': u'food'}, {u'count': 67, u'item': u'tv'}], u'_id': u'2015-05-22'}
```

with an item array per each day sorted by title occurence count.
Then in the application you can splice this array by n to get top N counts.
You can take a look at steps to reproduce it [in this example (in python)](http://miloncdn.appspot.com/docs/mongoUtils/_modules/mongoUtils/examples.html#Examples)

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, unfortunately that query returns 0 results.